# Restoring folder from a veracrypt encrypted SSD

Tags: veracrypt, ssd

By mistake a deleted an important folder from my computer and my ssd is encrypted with Veracrypt.

Any help how can I restore the folder?
It was from a crypto wallet.

I tried with recuva but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Since the disk is encrypted you're limited as to recovery options.

A utility which scans for files marked deleted, but not yet overwritten is pretty much your only option. You stated that this already didn't work.  Recuva has an option called Deep Scan.  Give that a go, it will take a very long time to run, and it's definitely not guaranteed to succeed.

Might you have a temporary copy somewhere?  Maybe you copied the file to a USB stick at some point?  You can recover deleted files off USB too, so you may give that a try.